# Having troubles libraries=places in google maps api <script>

Tags: javascript, spring, google-maps, thymeleaf

```js
var map;
var service;
var index = 0;
var posArray = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(init);

});

function init(location) {
    enable();
    googleMap();

    var currentLocation = {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude};

    var mapOptions = {
        center: currentLocation,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.READMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/jquery.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/client.js}"></script>
</head>
```

I am currently have trouble loading my `libraries=places` into my google maps api. The api will let me either use the key OR `libraries=places` but not both. The error shows:

> "Exception parsing document: template="index", line 10 - column 134"

line 10 is

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&libraries=places"
```

column 134 is the "=" between libraries and places.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What does the HTML sent to the browser look like?

Comment: Does the js snippet help? @geocodezip

Comment: No. It doesn't work and it doesn't include the HTML sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try blow is updated;

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(key='MY_KEY',libraries=places)}"></script>
```

Comment: When I applied your suggestion, the page did load but is showing the current messages:                                                                     localhost/:11 GET http://localhost:8080/@%7Bhttps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(key=AIzaSyCVQpVXVLkLwQaf5QKczw9ya6-uPcbftqs,libraries=places)%7D 404 ()                                                                   

client.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at init (client.js:20) .   @Venu Duggireddy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following code:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(libraries=places, key=MY_KEY)}"></script>
```